# Kryo serialization refuses to register class

Tags: scala, kryo

I'm trying to use kryo serialization with:

```
kryo.setRegistrationRequired(true);
```

I keep getting the following error saying that a certain class is not registered:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: com.my.package.MyClass[]
Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(com.my.package.MyClass[].class);
```

However, I do register it:

```
kryo.register(classOf[MyClass[_]])
```

When I set Log.TRACE() I get the following output:

```
00:11 TRACE: [kryo] Register class ID 51: com.my.package.MyClass (com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer)
```

Why does it say it is not registered, when the trace logger prints that it has been registered. I cannot find any useful documentation on the matter. Has anyone experienced this before? If it helps i'm running Apache Spark v0.8.1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. I was mistaking the java array syntax [] for the scala generic syntax []. The exception was being being thrown since I did not register an array of MyClass.

So in java

```
kryo.register( MyClass[].class );
```

And scala

```
kryo.register( classOf[ Array[ MyClass[_] ] ] )
```

Comment: Exactly the same problem I was having.  This worked.  Thanks!