# How to register Receiver[] with Kryo?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kryo

In the process of porting a Spark 1.6 app to Spark 2.0.2, there's this complaint in the log:

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver[]
Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver[].class);
```

This fails with `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/apache/spark/streaming/receiver/Receiver[]/class`:

```
sparkConf.set("spark.kryo.classesToRegister", "org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver[].class")
```

This fails with `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/apache/spark/streaming/receiver/Receiver[]`:

```
sparkConf.set("spark.kryo.classesToRegister", "org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver[]")
```

This fails with `Class is not registered: org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver[]`:

```
sparkConf.set("spark.kryo.classesToRegister", "org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver")
```

This fails with `Class is not registered: org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver[]`:

```
sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(Array(
    classOf[org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver[_]]
))
```

How can I get this class registered? I've been able to register other classes with Kryo, but not this one.

Edit:

In all these cases this setup is done:

```
sparkConf.set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true")
sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", classOf[KryoSerializer].getName)
GraphXUtils.registerKryoClasses(sparkConf)
```

Comment: Did you perhaps set `spark.kryo.registrationRequired` to `true` in your configuration?

Comment: @yuvalitzchakov - I've tried it set to true and to false. Set to false, I get an error about object 13994, but with no object name.

Comment: I would advise to set it to `false` and post the error message.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699278/how-can-the-kryo-complaint-under-spark-2-0-2-about-object-13994-be-fixed

Comment: This is really in the hopes of fixing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684098/how-to-fix-spark-losing-some-messages-sent-to-a-dstream

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found an approach that works here: [Kryo serialization refuses to register class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027451/kryo-serialization-refuses-to-register-class)

In short, change `classOf[org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver[_]],` to `classOf[Array[org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver[_]]],`