# How can the Kryo complaint under Spark 2.0.2 about object 13994 be fixed?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kryo

In the process of porting a Spark 1.6 app to Spark 2.0.2, there's this complaint in the log:

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 13994
```

This sometimes occurs after a couple batches have run, not the first time through. The setup is using:

```
sparkConf.set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "false")
```

Others have seen the same issue, but I haven't seen any resolutions. For example, [Kryo exception : Encountered unregistered class ID: 13994](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Kryo-exception-Encountered-unregistered-class-ID-13994-td22437.html)

I've tried switching to:

```
sparkConf.set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true")
```

and registering classes as suggested in one thread, but ran into [How to register Receiver[] with Kryo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683553/how-to-register-receiver-with-kryo).

Apparently there's no way to disable Kryo for certain classes, according to some blog chatter. Is there a way to determine what class it's not recognizing so that I can register it? Recompiling from source and changing the error message is one possible route, but perhaps there's an easier way. Better yet, is there a known fix for this?