# How to register InternalRow with Kryo in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2, kryo

I want to run Spark with Kryo serialisation. Therefore I set `spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer` and `spark.kryo.registrationRequired=true`

When I then run my code I get the error:

> Class is not registered: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow[]

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027451/kryo-serialization-refuses-to-register-class) I used

```
sc.getConf.registerKryoClasses(Array( classOf[ org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow[_] ] ))
```

But then the error is:

> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow does not take type parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use an external class as

```
class MyRegistrator extends KryoRegistrator {
override def registerClasses(kryo: Kryo) {
kryo.register(classOf[Array[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow]])
}
}
```

source : http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/tuning.html

Or if you want to register in your spark class

```
val cls: Class[Array[InternalRow]] = classOf[Array[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow]]

spark.sparkContext.getConf.registerKryoClasses(Array(cls))
```

I use the first one and works perfectly, I haven't tested the second one.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate ask if you need more help.