# spark kryo registration class missing

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, kryo

When forcing kryo registration via `spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true"` in spark 2.2 my error is

```
Class is not registered: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow[]
```

even when using:

```
.registerKryoClasses(
          Array(classOf[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.ofRef[_]],
                classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow])
        )
```

Obviously `InternalRow[]` would not compile in scala. What am I missing here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49109967/how-to-register-internalrow-with-kryo-in-spark?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa could be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to register InternalRow with Kryo in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49109967/how-to-register-internalrow-with-kryo-in-spark?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) is leading me to the correct answer.

```
classOf[Array[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow]]
```

is required. However then, further spark classes need to be added as you move forward.

Comment: https://github.com/bigdatagenomics/adam/blob/master/adam-core/src/main/scala/org/bdgenomics/adam/serialization/ADAMKryoRegistrator.scala has a great list of things to add